# Matlab getting results from parallel functions slow

Tags: performance, matlab, function, parallel-processing, parfor

I need to execute two Matlab functions in parallel. The problem is that getting results from them is much slower than execution.

First method:

```
spmd;
 if labindex==1, 
  K=MatricaK(NP, NE, r, Kxx, N, h, 1); %K is 1000x1000 matrix
 end;
 if labindex==2,
  F=Apkrovos(NP, NE, N, r, Ta, h, 1); %F is 1000x1 vector
 end;
end;
%This part is quite fast, around 0.17s.
K=K{1};
F=F{2};
%This part is very slow, around 1.15s.
```

Second method:

```
parfor i=1:2
 if i==1
  K=MatricaK(NP, NE, r, Kxx, N, h, 1); %this way doesn't return K outside the loop, but very fast, around 0.15 for all loop
 ..
  K{i}=MatricaK(NP, NE, r, Kxx, N, h, 1); %this works, but slow, around 1.5s
 ..
  K = [K MatricaK(NP, NE, r, Kxx, N, h, 1)]; %also works, but slow, around 1.5s
 ...
end;
```

How could I make the result returning fast? I found [Parallel Programming on MATLAB to execute 3 different functions at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248439/parallel-programming-on-matlab-to-execute-3-different-functions-at-the-same-time) but there is nothing about speed.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but why bother making it parallel at all if it's that fast to begin with?

Comment: First, I have to make my program parallel for a research. Second, I just want it to be faster than sequential version. Actually, it becomes ~40% faster than sequential (0.24 vs 0.17s) if I don't consider getting results. So, I wonder, if it is possible get the results fast :)

Comment: Surprising result! Does the speed differ when you run it for a second time (and when any pre initialization is done already) ? Also, does `K{:}` perhaps exceed what you can store efficiently (in Ram) ? can be checked by using 300 instead of 1000 once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is the overhead incurred passing the results around. While I can't give you a concrete answer - it depends on your situation and version of matlab - I can suggest some things to try.

1. Try different methods of retrieving the data from the matlabpool labs. Some of them may allow for matlab to do some behind the scenes optimisation. For this I would suggest looking at distributed arrays. Alternatively if you don't need to do any subsequent processing on the data you could just save it straight to disk rather than pass it through memory.
2. Try running it as a distributed [batch job](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/introduction-to-parallel-solutions.html#brjw1fx-2). The more recent versions of matlab allow you to create batch jobs and run them on your local machine (rather than on a dedicated cluster). Since your two functions are completely independent you could use this method which may be quicker for retrieving the data.
3. Try to find someway of having the results placed in shared memory. This is difficult since Matlab's parallel processing is based on MPI which works on message passing; some modes are basicly a matlab wrapper over MPI. This means that each worker is a separate instance of Matlab with a separate memory space and so when you gather the data again it is actually making an MPI message of it, which has some overhead. Ways to avoid this have been discussed on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872209/sharing-memory-between-processes-matlab) before.
4. Take a look inside the functions. If you can/are allowed to modify the two functions you are calling you may be able to parallelise them in a way which doesn't have such a communication overhead. Matlab is quite clever when it comes to parallel processing of vectors, so if there are any operations which you can translate into vector/matrix operations you could make a significant speed saving there without the need for the communication overhead.
5. Try something other than matlab. If you have the time and coding skills then you could re-code the functions in a language which allows multi-threaded execution such as C++ with OpenMP.

I have faced similar problems with parallel programming in Matlab myself, though in my case despite sharing input data the problem was embarrassingly parallel so I ended up saving the output to disk straight from the worker nodes.

Comment: What leads you to the conclusion that `the problem is the overhead incurred passing the results around`? Overhead typically is a problem when you do small things inside the parfor, but that is definately not the case here.

Comment: In the original question the first method cleanly separates the actual work (calling the two methods) from the getting the data (`k=k{1}`) and gives the time taken for each step. The method calls take a total of 0.17s, while the results passing takes 1.15s.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. Now I got around 10x shorter time results after doing nothing and now both times (execution and data retrieving) are equal for 1000 e., but with more elements data retrieving time is increasing. It seems I am testing not appropriate program, because it uses a lot of data for not extensive execution.